# onnx2nnoir: command not found after installation of nnoir-onnx

Tags: pypi, onnx

I've downloaded an `.onnx` model (https://github.com/onnx/models/blob/main/vision/classification/resnet/model/resnet50-v2-7.onnx) and trying to convert in to `.nnoir` format. I've renamed the file to `model.onnx` and trying to convert it using the command lines given in the **Example** section of the library description(https://pypi.org/project/nnoir-onnx/).
But the command lines are being problematic so I am not being able to convert the model to `.nnoir` format.
The logs are attached as a `.txt` file and also given below.
[onnx-nnoir.txt](https://github.com/Idein/nnoir/files/9177835/onnx-nnoir.txt)

```
user02@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ onnx2nnoir -o model.nnoir model.onnx
onnx2nnoir: command not found
user02@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ pip install nnoir-onnx
Requirement already satisfied: nnoir-onnx in /home/user02/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.0.15)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata<5,>=4 in /home/user02/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from nnoir-onnx) (4.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: msgpack<2,>=1 in /home/user02/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from nnoir-onnx) (1.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: onnx<1.12.0 in /home/user02/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from nnoir-onnx) (1.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy<2,>=1 in /home/user02/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from nnoir-onnx) (1.23.1)
Requirement already satisfied: nnoir<2.0.0,>=1.0.9 in /home/user02/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from nnoir-onnx) (1.0.9)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf<4.0,>=3.8 in /home/user02/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from nnoir-onnx) (3.20.1)
Requirement already satisfied: onnxruntime<2.0.0,>=1.2.0 in /home/user02/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from nnoir-onnx) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in /home/user02/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from importlib-metadata<5,>=4->nnoir-onnx) (3.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=3.6.2.1 in /home/user02/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from onnx<1.12.0->nnoir-onnx) (4.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: flatbuffers in /home/user02/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from onnxruntime<2.0.0,>=1.2.0->nnoir-onnx) (2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: coloredlogs in /home/user02/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from onnxruntime<2.0.0,>=1.2.0->nnoir-onnx) (15.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in /home/user02/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from onnxruntime<2.0.0,>=1.2.0->nnoir-onnx) (21.3)
Requirement already satisfied: sympy in /home/user02/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from onnxruntime<2.0.0,>=1.2.0->nnoir-onnx) (1.10.1)
Requirement already satisfied: humanfriendly>=9.1 in /home/user02/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from coloredlogs->onnxruntime<2.0.0,>=1.2.0->nnoir-onnx) (10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=3.0.5,>=2.0.2 in /home/user02/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from packaging->onnxruntime<2.0.0,>=1.2.0->nnoir-onnx) (3.0.9)
Requirement already satisfied: mpmath>=0.19 in /home/user02/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from sympy->onnxruntime<2.0.0,>=1.2.0->nnoir-onnx) (1.2.1)
user02@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ onnx2nnoir -o model.nnoir model.onnx
onnx2nnoir: command not found
user02@ubuntu:~/Downloads$
```

I have also tried `onnigiri` but similar errors are being displayed. Kindly let me know how to solve this.

Comment: Could you show the output of `which onnx2nnoir`?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The output is as following -
```user02@ubuntu:~$ which onnx2nnoir

/home/user02/.local/bin/onnx2nnoir```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because in Linux, `pip install ...` command will add library into `.local/bin` folder, and your machine hasn't had `.local/bin` in your `PATH`
Execute this line before converting

```
export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

Or better way is to append the above line to `~/.bashrc` file in your machine. And activate it by

```
source ~/.bashrc
```